# How to connect to redis in one of my cloud function?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-functions

I have a several `cloud function` with below file structures

```
root
 |_ functions
        |___src
             |___services
             |       |___function1.ts
             |       |___function2.ts
             |       |___function3.ts
             |
             |___index.tx
```

In my index, I import all of the functions, then export it to for the cloud functions

```
//index.ts

const function1 = require(./services/function1)
const function2 = require(./services/function2)
const function3 = require(./services/function3)

exports.function1 = function1.function1
exports.function2 = function2.function2
exports.function3 = function3.function3
```

Then, only in my function1 I want to use redis, So I included redis in my function1
Here is my **redis.ts**

```
import * as redis from "redis";

const REDISHOST = process.env.REDISHOST || 'localhost';
const REDISPORT = Number(process.env.REDISPORT || 6379);

const redisClient = redis.createClient({
  socket: {
    host: REDISHOST,
    port: REDISPORT,
  },
});
redisClient.on('error', err => console.error('ERR:REDIS:', err));
redisClient.connect();

export default redisClient;
```

And I import it in my function1 as follow :

```
import redisClient from "../common/redis"

exports.function1 = onRequest(logic)
```

I could successfully connect to the redis with my function1. But the problem is, when I'm deploying the function2 and function3, it is also trying to connect to the redis even though I'm not importing the redis client to my function2 and function3.

What did I do wrong in here?

Comment: If you have three different functions, why don’t you have three different indexes and deploy three different functions?

Comment: @aleph how could I have multiple index files? how should the structures be? My current file structure, I also get it from the google. So, I dont know how to create multiple index files.

Comment: I don’t know how you are routing and instantiating in the real code but first thing I would check is why function2 is trying to talk to Redis.

Comment: @aleph your question seems like has been answered by Doug Stevenson with his answer. But I'm still wondering what is the downside with the official recommendation from Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to realize is that your index.ts is executed *in its entirety* for each function that you export from it.  That means each function is going to, as part of its execution, on a cold start of a new server instance:

1. require ./services/function1
2. import redis.ts
3. create an instance of the `redisClient` global

What you should do instead is not define `redisClient` as a global variable that always gets created whenever the module is loaded.  Defer the creation to whenever the client is actually used, and cache it in a global if you want, to be available on subsequent invocations of the function on the same server instance..

Comment: This is a good idea. But in the [google official site](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-functions#node.js_1), it is recommending to use the `redisClient` as the client globally. Do you know, if I move the redisClient to each function, and init and connect it when I use, what is the downside if compared to the global init?

Comment: That's just a minimal sample for a single function, meant to be easy to understand. It's not a recommendation for all cases for all time.  You really need to delay the creation of the client so that it only happens in the function where it's needed.  There is no practical downside to this.  I've done this before and I recommend it to my clients - it works fine.